# SAML SP: Trust the IdP's certificate

Tags: xml, saml, saml-2.0, simplesamlphp

Im the SP and want to validate the signatures from IdP. The IdP told me that our SP is not trusting the IdP's certificate.

From my understanding this happens:

```
SP-> SAML request digitally signed with private key of SP
IdP-> SAML request gets verified with public key of SP (from metadata)

IdP-> SAML response signed with private key of IdP
SP-> SAML response gets verified with public key of IdP (from metadata)
```

So how would I need to trust the IdP's certificate? Isnt it enough when it gets validated with the public key provided in the metadata? Do I need to import something from the IdP into my cert folder?

Comment: Sound like a misunderstanding. The trust is normally set up by importing the metadata. Maby you need to add a certificate for the CA that issued the IdP certificate it that is not already trused by your system

Comment: How would I tell my system that the certificate is trusted? I was thinking that its enough to import the IdPs metadata which contains the certificate.

Comment: Depend what IdP you are using. You say that the IdP told you that the SP is not trusting their certificate. Did you get a error message that you sent to them? Or how did they know this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to think about things is that signing should always be done with the private key, and validation should always be done with the public key.

In the SP-initiated standard web flow, here is the explanation of where and how certificates are used:

- `SP --> IdP` The AuthnRequest sent by SP is signed using the SP's private key, the IdP validates the AuthnRequest signature with the SP's public key
- `IdP --> SP` At least a portion of the SamlResponse sent by the IdP will be signed. If the whole response isn't, then the assertion inside should be. If the whole response is signed, then the assertion doesn't have to be. In either case, the signing will be with the IdP's private key, and the SP will validate it with the IdP's public key.

Some products (and probably all of the DIY systems/libraries) may allow you to sign both the response and the assertion, but there's no reason for that - none. It provides no additional benefit over and above the signing of the response alone.

As Stefan notes in his comments on the question, this "problem" is typically solved in products by using metadata transfers to configure themselves, rather than just an email exchange of some URLs and public keys. The typical flow for Metadata Exchange is the SP provides a baseline metadata file to the IdP that defines the SPs ACS URL, the SP's public key for signature validation, and the attributes that their application *requires*. Then the IdP loads that, figures out what attributes they have that fulfills the SP's attribute requirements, and then generates their metadata containing their protocol URLs (like where authentication requests should be sent) and certificates and whatnot, sending it back to the SP. The SP loads it, and you're off to the races.